# Rearrange divs / dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reaarrange some divs, when the screensize is lower than 768... 
If you take a closer look at the HTML below, then you will see the structure is in a 2 columns. When the screensize is lower than 768, I want the  to be arranged so that it is the first element in

Is there any jquery plugin or something out there, so that you can move divs around?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <!-- Left Col -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 nopad">
            <div class="col-contain pull-right">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="#" class="logo-brand">
                            <img src="_assets/img/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" title="" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <figure class="img-text-box large first" style="background: transparent url(images/large-1.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
                <img src="images/large-1.jpg" style="visibility:hidden;" />
                <figcaption class="col-contain pull-right text">
                    A text here
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <section class="press module clearfix">
                Some content here
            </section>
            <section class="newsletter clearfix">
                Some content here
            </section>
        </div>
        <!--- Right Col -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 nopad">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default cl-effect-5" role="navigation">
                A navigation here
            </nav>
            <figure class="img-text-box large second" style="background: transparent url(images/large-2.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
                <img src="images/large-2.jpg" style="visibility:hidden;" />
                <figcaption class="text">
                    A text here
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <section class="news module clearfix">
                Some content here
            </section>
            <section class="countdown module clearfix">
                Some content here
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <footer>
            My footer
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with CSS media queries?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense, "I want the to be arranged so that it is the first element in " ...the what to be the first in what?

Comment: The left-col <!-- Left Col -->

Answer (score 0):

You can do it making responsive as 
for making your css you should know about @media screen

```
   @media(max-width:390px), @media(max-width:480px).. etc
```

there is one more process, If you have limited no. of div, then you can do it by jQuery:

```
  screen.width
  screen.height
  screen.availWidth
  screen.availHeight
  screen.colorDepth
  screen.pixelDepth
```

Comment: Cant do it with media queries, as I have to move dom elements around